# Can my company know if I visited adult websites while connected to their VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I use Cisco Anyconnect on my personal computer to connect to some services only available to my company's staff like timesheets etc. Yesterday I connected and forgot it connected, I then browsed adult websites for about 30 minutes.

I tried to understand how it works but I can't get a definite answer. When I check what my external IP is while connected to the VPN and not connected, it is the same.  I don't want the company to know about this, is it possible that these sites have been logged?

The diagram below exists in one of their manuals.  It looks like it doesnt always connect to their servers.  Can anyone with some knowledge shed some light on this subject?

[image]

Comment: Of course they can.  It depends on their setup.

Comment: Every company has different policies and procedures for VPN connections. There is no way for us to know what your company has setup for security and/or tracking. Corporate networking is off topic anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but if your external IP was the same, your actual requests to site probably didn't go through the VPN, but your DNS lookups may have hit your company DNS server.  So xhamster.com, livejasmin.com, etc. will appear in any DNS logs, but not things like specific pages you were viewing.

Sounds like your company may have implemented "split-tunneling", but for this to work properly I think you need to be using your company's DNS server over the VPN and not your ISPs or one you've set locally, and the AnyConnect client sets that up.

Politically, if they happen to confront you with this, which is unlikely unless they monitor DNS very closely (and if they were monitoring it closely, they'd probably implement filtering software and you'd likely be blocked), you should say you believe this was the result of malware on your home computer and are taking it somewhere to get looked at ("Gosh, y'know my system has been so slow at home anyway I might have some virus or something.").  Offer to take a company loaner laptop home for VPN use instead of your system.